# twilio <stream> websocket streaming to signalR asp.net core 3.0

Tags: websocket, signalr, twilio

Sorry if this is a silly question.  Has anyone managed to get the twilio stream to websocket working with SignalR (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream).

I have been trying for a while now and although I can see its hitting the server I never see it hit any of the methods.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Can you share the code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I am just taking a look at Twilio Streams now that they've announced [bidirectional support](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/bi-directional-streaming-support-media-streams), I noticed that the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream) indicate you have to utilize WebSockets. SignalR uses WebSockets but isn't just WebSockets. It's summed up succinctly in [Jim Mc̮̑̑̑͒G's](https://twitter.com/siliconorchid) blog post **[How to save an audio file from Twilio Media streams to Azure storage](https://blogs.siliconorchid.com/post/coding-inspiration/twilio-mediastreams/)**

"SignalR is terrific, but it solves a different problem. SignalR can be thought of as a wrapper of several technologies - of which WebSockets represent a major component. It primarily serves the purpose of connecting web-browser clients to a back-end service. Other problems it solves include the maintenance of robust connections and the use of fallback techniques to enable browsers that don’t natively support WebSockets, to still benefit from real-time connections.

*For Twilio Media Streams, we need to use WebSocket connections in a server-to-server configuration. SignalR isn’t the right tool for that job.*"

Comment: hi, yes i did actually get the websocket running under asp.net core and it seems to work well but i am still unable to connect it to Azure cognitive services - have you had any luck?